# What does a pilot have to do in order to fly as a second in command in a private jet?

Tags: faa-regulations, flight-training

If a pilot has the opportunity to fly as an SIC in a private jet, what FAA requirements must they comply with in order to fly with passengers?

Answer (score 4):

Don't know if the same rules still apply, but back in the 70s and 80s I used to fly legally as the second pilot on corporate jets with just a commercial license with IFR and multi-engine ratings. At the time I had no type ratings.

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically you can fly a Boeing 747 on a Private Pilots Licence as long as you have the relevant type ratings. If you are flying passengers for profit you will then require at least a Commercial Pilots Licence.

Modern day training courses which prepare you to be the first officer or co-pilot as it were, tend to result in you holding a frozen ATPL, ie, you have done all the exams and you're now hour building in order to qualify for the licence. You will also likely have completed a Multi-Crew Co-operation course of some description, obtained your jet rating and hold any relevant Instrument Ratings. It probably depends on which provider you were choosing to apply for.

EDIT: Ah, my apologies, this post was in relation to European (EASA) guidelines (more specifically in the UK really).

Comment: If it were a privately operated 747 (which my question is about, not airline) then you don't even need a type rating do you?

Comment: In the UK at least, you would need to be converted onto type. Else you could just step from a Cessna 152 into a Boeing 747 after getting a jet rating, and obviously if you do not know how to fly the aircraft, you're in a bit of trouble! :D

Comment: In the US, no type rating is required for the **SIC**, however it is for the PIC.

Answer (score 0):

In general, FAR Part 61, section 55a,b outlines specific requirements for those designated as Second-in-command of Aircraft requiring more than one pilot.  Section b probably covers the specific training you're curious about. See also parts 121, 125, and 135 for more specific requirements.

Comment: H brinky, welcome to Aviation StackOverflow!  When answering questions, we prefer that you include the pertinent wording from the sources that you quote, (and even a link to it if you have it handy!) so that the question is answered in one place.  Please click the *edit* link at the bottom of your answer to add more details if you want to improve it.  For more info, see [answer], thanks!

Answer (score 0):

SIC: instrument rating, multi-engine (if more than one engine) Endorsements: high performance (200hp or greater)-high altitude - complex (retractable landing gear)

Comment: Jets are not “complex” because they don’t have a controllable-pitch prop.

Comment: @StephenS depends on jurisdiction. AFAIK under EASA anything with multiple engines and/or retracting gear is automatically complex.